# Catch exception in string (from XML-file) to int conversion, when string is empty

Tags: c#, exception

I have a program that fills a datagrid from an XML-file.

This is a part of my code:

```
public class Input
    {
        public string dummyText { get; set; }
        
        public string dummyText { get; set; }

        public int dummyText { get; set; } //int value needed here

        public string dummyText { get; set; }

        public string dummyText { get; set; }
    }

    private void fill_dataGrid()
    {
        List<Input> users = new List<Input>();

        foreach (XElement el in xdoc.Descendants("dummyText"))
        {
            users.Add(new Input()
            {
                dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
                dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
                hereProblem = Convert.ToInt32(el.Element("dummyText").Value), // pot. error here
                dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
                dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value
            });
        }

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
    }
```

At the line which is marked with "hereProblem" i want to convert the XML-value which is a string to an integer. But sometimes there is no value to convert so it throws an error.

**Question**: How can i handle the exception for this one value that it does just nothing when there is no value to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i handle the exception for this one value that it does just nothing when there is no value to convert.

Consider [using `int.TryParse(string input, out int Output)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0).

`TryParse()` returns a bool that tells you if it fails to convert a string to an int or not. It also sets the out value to a default value(0) so you don't have to worry about the value being un-initiliazed.

For example:

```cs
if(int.TryParse(el.Element("dummyText").Value, out int foundValue))
{
    users.Add(new Input()
    {
        dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
        dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
        hereProblem = foundValue,
        dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value,
        dummyText = el.Element("dummyText").Value
    });
}
else
{
 // do something else, or nothing.
}
```

Comment: int.Parse will also throw an exception when input is an empty string though

Comment: Yup it sure will! It completely slipped my mind, *even though i literally just read the MSDN for it and posted a link to it*